# Multiple Google Drive Accounts (grive)

Tags: cloud, google, accounts, grive

I have installed grive for my Google Drive integration in Ubuntu 12.04, Can I to add multiple google accounts with multiple grive instances? I'm doing something similar with Dropbox then I would think that I can do the same with Grive.

Thanks

Comment: There used to be "Syncdrive" but it has been discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with the GUI, but it is really simple with the command line:

I'll assume, for the sake of my explanation, that you want to create a repository for your private data and one for your work data.

1) Open a new Terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2) Create a new directory with `mkdir private_drive`.
3) Enter your directory with `cd private_drive`.
4) Initialize a grive repository with the command `grive -a`.
5) The terminal shows you a link. Open it with your browser and connect via your private Google account. Paste the token code in your terminal (with right click, CTRL+V doesn't work) and press enter.
6) Come back to the parent directory with `cd ..`.
7) Repeat steps 2) through 5) with the directory `work_drive` and your work Google account.

**Notes:**

- As far as I know, it is not possible to auto-sync the directories. To do so, open a terminal, go to the directory and simply run the command `grive`.
- More options are available, check the tiny help message with the command `grive -h`.