# How to setup overGrive with multiple accounts?

Tags: 14.04, google-drive, grive

OverGrive web site lists several features including "Sync Multiple Accounts". I downloaded the test version, set up one account. Then wanted to add another account but have no clue how is one supposed to do that.

There is no manual and googling did not help. There is no option in GUI to add another account. If I try to run another instance of overDrive, no surprise, I get this:

```
$ python /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive
overGrive instance already running
```

Are multiple accounts not available afterall? Are mutiple accounts not available in test version? Has anyone managed to set up multiple accounts and if yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

For now, one can not. Got a reply from developer Christiaan Diedricks on this:

> "Currently you cannot sync two accounts at the same time. Google does not allow this. You need to connect one account - sync, then connect the other and sync. This can be done in the trial version. We are working on making multiple accounts easier to manage."

### Workaround

I found that I have installed a `grive2` package some years ago. With this, from CLI, it can be done as described here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/530163

To automate `grive2` syncing with Google Drive, one can use `crontab`

1. In terminal, open up user crontab for editing :

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```
2. Enter the following line in crontab to have it sync every 15 minutes (replace username and google_drive with your username and folder you want to sync):

   ```
   */15 * * * * grive --path /home/username/google_drive/
   ```
3. Save your crontab file